# if __name__ == "__main__" on Imports

Tags: python, import, nested, program-entry-point

I'm working on two python files.  Once I am done, I plan to call one from from another:

```
main.py
import os, re, time, logging, sys, subprocess, operator, datetime, pprint, dbfread, collections, calendar, xlwt, xlrd, errno, platform, stat
import subfile
# A long body of codes that does things

subfile.py
import os, re, time, logging, sys, subprocess, operator, datetime, pprint, dbfread, collections, calendar, xlwt, xlrd, errno, platform, stat
# Another long body of codes that does things
```

If I call main.py, I expect it to run `subfile.py` also.  Occasionally, I will run `subfile.py` separately and would like for it to run normally on its own.  Now, in `subfile.py`, should I nest the import commands under `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

```
subfile.py
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    import os, re, time, logging, sys, subprocess, operator, datetime, pprint, dbfread, collections, calendar, xlwt, xlrd, errno, platform, stat
# Another long body of codes that does things
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your motivation is to avoid multiple imports of the very same module, don't be afraid of that.

Import of an already imported module is almost a no-op, basically just one lookup in the dict of modules.

So there is no gain, just the downside of making the program little bit more complicated and less readable.

Answer (score 1):

No, as a general rule, place your imports at the top of the file, and let python manage it. There may be some cases where an import should be placed inside a class/method/function, but this is not one of them.

If things got more complicated, you could place the imports in the `__init__.py` for the package.